# How can I display all the tags from each category

Tags: django, django-taggit

this is link model:

```
class Link(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.URLField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

this is category:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Category"), max_length=255)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

if I want to display link.tags in link_detail page I can do it with this:

```
{% for tag in link.tags.all %}
   <a href="{% url 'tagged' tag.name %}">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But I couldnt figure out how can I display all tags from one category ?
Forexample I have 2 links in A category which have 2 tags:python, django. I want to display these  like this:

```
A category tags : python, django
```

What is the best solution?Thanks for any help.

Comment: `tags = TaggableManager()` ?? Looks like it is a manager. Please verify the model structure ?

Comment: Have you tried "Category.link_set.all().values_list('tags', flat=True)"